# java game development restricted number randomly objects

Tags: java, object, random, project

Im creating a game. I need to create objects randomly but i want them to come in a certain number. Here is my main class code for randomly created object

```
private void randomTiles() {

    int randomXtile = new Random().nextInt(9500) + 20;
    int randomYtile = new Random().nextInt(12) + 0;
    Tile t = new Tile(randomXtile, randomYtile, 3);
    tilearray.add(t);
}

private void updateTiles() {
    randomTiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < tilearray.size(); i++) {
        Tile t = (Tile) tilearray.get(i);
        t.update();
    }
}

private void paintTiles(Graphics g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tilearray.size(); i++) {
        Tile t = (Tile) tilearray.get(i);
        g.drawImage(t.getTileImage(), t.getTileX(), t.getTileY(), this);
    }
}
```

tile constructor is

```
public Tile(int x, int y, int typeInt) {

    tileX = x * 40;
    tileY = y * 40;

    type = typeInt;
    r = new Rectangle();
    if (type == 5) {
        tileImage = StartingClass.tiledirt;
    } else if (type == 8) {
        tileImage = StartingClass.tilegrassTop;
    } else if (type == 4) {
        tileImage = StartingClass.tilegrassLeft;
    } else if (type == 6) {
        tileImage = StartingClass.tilegrassRight;

    } else if (type == 2) {
        tileImage = StartingClass.tilegrassBot;
    } else if (type == 3) {
        tileImage = StartingClass.ice;
        hp = 2;
    } else {
        type = 0;
    }

}
```

and somewhere in my game object should come at certain coordinates. Can you help me about this ?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a bit confused at your problem. Where is your code where you show an attempt to create multiple Tiles? And how many Tiles? Is the number of Tiles that you want to create at each creation point fixed? If so, could you create them in a simple for loop? Please clarify your problem a bit more.

Comment: At RandomTiles() i give a tile randomly coordinates, my tiles are  40x40 pixels so i multiply x and y coordinates with 40 to place them correct position and then i'm adding them to an array. At UpdateTiles() updating them to their new positions and then i'm painting tiles but the point is This randomly coordinates are between 12*40 x coordinates and 9500 * 40 coordinates ( i give 9500 because i want them to less chance to create ) and they can be 20 25 15 tile in screen sometimes i dont want that. I want maybe 3 displayed tiles in screen at once ...

Comment: Define "tiles in screen"? Is this the number of Tiles in the array list? Or are not all the Tiles in the array list showing because they are off the screen somewhere, and "tiles in screen" will be the number of Tiles showing in some viewport of your logical game area?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/bf87in6kx/  these boxes are the tiles in screen. As you can see there are many boxes in screen but i want a certain number of boxes at certain coordinates which placed randomly. And yes they are off the screen somewhere because i give the random x coordinate between 0 and (9500 * 40) and yes tiles in screen will be the number of tiles showing in viewport ...